# I would like to remove using namespace std from this code, but am unsure what all needs to be prefixed with std::

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to remove using namespace std, but I don't know what all needs to be prefixed.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "PlayingCard.h"

 using namespace std;

 PlayingCard makeValidCard(int value, int suit);

 int main()
{
// Create a playing card
PlayingCard card1;


// Test the default constructor and GetCardCode
cout << "Testing default constructor. Expect card code to be 00\n card code is :";
cout << card1.getCardCode() << endl << endl;


// Test the setter and getter
cout << "Seting card to 'AH' using SetValue and SetSuit" << endl;
card1.setCard('A', 'H');
cout << "GetValue returns :" << card1.getValue() << endl;
cout << "GetSuit returns :" << card1.getSuit() << endl << endl;


// Test overloaded constructor
PlayingCard tenOfSpades('T', 'S');
cout << "Testing overloaded constructor. Expect card code to be TS\n card code is :";
cout << tenOfSpades.getCardCode() << endl << endl;


// Test IsValid with valid cards
cout << "Testing valid card codes.\n"
     << "Expect isValid to return true for all (except perhaps Jokers.)"
      << endl;
// Create and test valid cards
int validCards = 0;     // cards that return true for IsValid
int invalidCards = 0;   // cards that return false for IsValid

// Create and test four suits plus the jokers
for(int suit = 1; suit <= 5; suit++)
{
    // Create and test ace, 2 - 9, Jack, Queen, and King
    for(int value = 1; value <= 13; value++)
    {
        PlayingCard aCard = makeValidCard(value, suit);
       cout << "Card Code: " << aCard.getCardCode() << " IsValid :";
       if (aCard.isValid())
       {
           validCards++;
            cout << "true" << endl;
       }
        else
        {
            invalidCards++;
            cout << "false" << endl;
        }
    // suit 5 is just for creating the two Jokers
    if (suit == 5 && value >= 2)
        break;
    }
}
cout << "IsValid returned false for " << invalidCards << " card codes" << endl;
cout << "IsValid returned true for " << validCards << " card codes" << endl;
cout << endl;


// Test IsValid with invalid cards
// Create and test invalid cards
cout << "Testing invalid card codes; isValid should return false for all." << endl;
validCards = 0;
invalidCards = 0;
   // Loop through all possible ASCII character codes for card codes
   for(int suit = 0; suit <= 255; suit++)
   for(int value = 0; value <= 255; value++)
   {
        // Only check card codes that are not valid
        PlayingCard aCard = makeValidCard(value, suit);
        if (aCard.getCardCode() == "00")
        {
            if (aCard.isValid())
            {
               cout << "value :" << value << " suit :" <<suit << " IsValid :";
               cout << "true" << endl;
               validCards++;
            }
            else
            {
                invalidCards++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "IsValid returned false for " << invalidCards << " card codes" << endl;
    cout << "IsValid returned true for " << validCards << " card codes" << endl;

return 0;
}


/******************************************************/
/* Test Functions                                     */
/******************************************************/

PlayingCard makeValidCard(int iValue, int iSuit)
{
char value = '0';
char suit = '0';


    switch (iValue)
    {
        case 1:
           value = 'A';
           break;
        case 10:
            value = 'T';
            break;
        case 11:
           value = 'J';
           break;
        case 12:
           value = 'Q';
           break;
        case 13:
           value = 'K';
           break;
        default:
            if ((iValue >= 2) && (iValue <= 9))
                value = '0' + iValue;
            break;
    }


   switch (iSuit)
    {
        case 1:
           suit = 'D';
           break;
        case 2:
           suit = 'S';
           break;
        case 3:
           suit = 'C';
           break;
        case 4:
           suit = 'H';
           break;
        // Special case for the Joker
        case 5:
            if(iValue == 1)
            {
                value = 'Z';
                suit = 'B';
            }
            else if(iValue == 2)
            {
                value = 'Z';
                suit = 'R';
            }
            else
            {
                value = '0';
                suit = '0';
            }
            break;
    }

    PlayingCard testCard(value, suit);
    return testCard;
}
```

Comment: The short version is "pretty much anything from the C++ standard library". The C standard library isn't in the std namespace, and neither are primitive types (int, char, etc). In your case it looks like the main things you're using from the C++ standard library are cout and endl, which will need to be prefixed with std::

Comment: LOL - you have just showed why it is a really bad idea to use `using namespace` in source files. "How do I then know what namespace the names belong to?" +1 :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove it and then prefix everything that the compiler errors on. :P

---

With a quick glance, what definitely needs to be prefixed are `cout` and `endl`.
Also, please ***do not*** use `endl` to just insert newlines, use plain old `'\n'` instead. `endl` not only inserts a newline, but also flushs the stream, which can be quite the performance penalty if used frequently (which you do). Only use it if you need the stream flushed in addition to inserting a newline.

Comment: There is no performance penalty for using endl in a simple console program like this. Most similar programs will spend 99.9% of its time waiting for cin anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look over the code with a fine tooth comb, but probably just `cout` and `endl`.  If the compiler gives you an error about an undefined symbol, try adding std to that too.  Incidentally, you could also change `using namespace std;` to `using std::cout;` and `using std::endl;`  That would keep the global namespace from being overly polluted, but avoid adding the qualifier to every instance in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The only two I see are `cout` and `endl` everything else is a keyword or user defined.

Answer (score 1):

Given the frequency that you use `cout`, you might want to replace `using namespace std;` with `using std::cout;`.

As Xeo says, you should search-and-replace `endl` with `'\n'`.

It looks like that might cover all your bases. Fix any other compiler errors by adding `std::` as they appear.